# How different human society and behaviour would be if the talion law was imposed by a benevolent goddess since the creation of mankind?

Tags: society, magic, modern-age, gods

In another universe and another dimension, humanity is created by an omnipotent and benevolent goddess.

The planet in which these humans inhabit is a perfect clone of the earth and the goddess is worshiped with different names and forms but is essentially the same entity.

The goddess creates strict rules to maintain order and humans soon realize that this alternate world is governed by the law of talion,Eye per eye,Teeth per teeth.

If a human kills another, Is punished with death in 24 hours in various ways depending on the cruelty of the crime, For example, Thunder, Wild animals commanded by the will of the goddess, Horrible diseases etc.

What would a modern society look like in this dimension, taking into account that wars and conflicts between humans do not exist?

Comment: This depends heavily on what is punished and what is not, and when something is considered "your fault" vs an accident, or just unfortunate circumstance.

Comment: It certainly is important. For example, does poisoning count as killing? What if left a bottle of bleach somewhere, and some kid drank it? What if I gave peanuts to a guy who is allergic but I didn't know about it? Your people would be _intimately_ familiar with these rules, and they decide to a large extent what happens.

Comment: I think I've seen variants of this questions multiple times on this Stack, so it's not very original. It mostly just doesn't really work because it breaks down over the details of enforcement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79301/discussion-between-seraph-myrmidon-and-erik).

Comment: Hi there. Please don't keep vandalizing the question. Questions do exist for the benefit of the entire community, not just one user. They're put on hold not because they're terrible and should be deleted - that's usually not true - but because the author needs to take time to improve them and make them better, at which point they can be reopened. I'm going to temporarily lock this question;  when the lock expires, you can take the time to edit it and make it better. Feel free to talk to folks in chat if anyone wants to help.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't look like anything at all. The human race would have died out completely within a generation or maybe two; you haven't changed the basic competitive nature of the human animal you've just made that nature immediately lethal. Unless the goddess creates humans that aren't strictly speaking human the same way the modern H. Sapiens Sapiens are then they will still compete, still kill each other and they'll be gone in short order. The [second story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel) of how our race began in the [book religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahamic_religions) is about a brother killing his sibling, under "the law of talion" they'd both have died and that would be the end of the tale. How true that particular story is is irrelevant, it speaks to the essential nature of mankind. My point is humans kill things, especially we kill each other, we're really good at it and we're not going to stop any time soon.

Comment: Why did you answer if you think this question should be closed?

Comment: @SeraphMyrmidon Because, as is often the case, I answered the question _before_ I really thought about the content.

Comment: Wouldn't that just mean that the fittest which survive would be the least competitive most socially minded people? (Humanity would turn out less like chimpanzee and more like bonobos.) Unless they would be killed in turn by wild animals.

Comment: @RealSubtle Sure that could happen but they wouldn't be what we know as humans anymore, they'd be a much more peaceable species, whether they'd survive that or not would, in this case, be at the whim of the goddess.

Comment: @Ash well, it depends on whether the OP was asking about humans as a biological species, i.e. "Homo Sapiens" or humans as a social label. In some sci-fi, all intelligent species  on whose the term "human rights" is applicable are called humans.

Comment: @RealSubtle I take "the planet in which these humans inhabit is a perfect clone of the earth" to mean that the inhabitants are perfectly human as we currently define the human condition also and have written my answer accordingly. When the question unlocks you're welcome to write an answer based on an alternate interpretation, I'm just telling it how I see it.

Comment: *"When the question unlocks you're welcome to write an answer"* It'd need to be reopened first, too.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling There is that, I have seen stranger questions work on the stack, there's no reason that it couldn't clear the bar with some good editing.

Comment: @Ash Maybe the first thing to do would be to ask for a clarification. :)

Comment: Yeah; "what would society look like?" *is* what's typically universally considered too broad (not primarily opinion-based) for Worldbuilding, but if this question could somehow be narrowed down to focus on one aspect of society, it might be reopenable. I could easily imagine a few interesting (and answerable) questions based on OP's premise, but since I have no idea what they're really after, I'm not going to edit. Also, OP has been temporarily suspended, but should hopefully be back to provide clarification in a week as per their profile.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I hope so, it's not an inherently bad question, just like you say it lacks some focus.